# Need help in automating the testing of a REST API

Tags: java, rest, api, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to test a **REST API** in [**Postman**](https://www.getpostman.com/) (Chrome extension) via an automated process using Selenium WebDriver.

I don't know how to launch **Postman** by using Selenium WebDriver. Can anyone help me, or provide me with a working example for launching Postman? Any other *idea/example/suggestion* to automate REST API testing (w/o Postman) is more than welcome! (I will need the complete Java code for this)

Comment: Postman is an interactive tool; there are much better options for automatically testing APIs.

Answer (score 1):

RestAssured is quite good for this - http://rest-assured.io/

Good for validating your APIs.